# R Calculate days around an event day

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data.frame and I want to create a new column with the number of days around a certain event.

Here is my dataframe:

```
df <- tibble(
  date= lubridate::today()+c(1:7),
  event=c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA)
)

df
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  date       event
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2020-01-21    NA
2 2020-01-22    NA
3 2020-01-23    NA
4 2020-01-24     1
5 2020-01-25    NA
6 2020-01-26    NA
7 2020-01-27    NA
```

And here is my desired output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  date       event days_around
  <date>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2020-01-21    NA          -3
2 2020-01-22    NA          -2
3 2020-01-23    NA          -1
4 2020-01-24     1           0
5 2020-01-25    NA           1
6 2020-01-26    NA           2
7 2020-01-27    NA           3
```

Does anyone have an idea how can I solve my problem?

Perhaps in conjunction with the `seq_along` or `rleid` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use :

```
df$days_around <- seq_along(df$date) - which(df$event == 1)
#Or use which.max
#df$days_around <- seq_along(df$date) - which.max(df$event)

#   date       event days_around
#  <date>     <dbl>       <int>
#1 2020-01-21    NA          -3
#2 2020-01-22    NA          -2
#3 2020-01-23    NA          -1
#4 2020-01-24     1           0
#5 2020-01-25    NA           1
#6 2020-01-26    NA           2
#7 2020-01-27    NA           3
```

In `dplyr` that would be :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(days_around = row_number() - which(event == 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution

```
df <- within(df, days_around <- seq(nrow(df))-which(!is.na(event)))
```

such that

```
> df
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  date       event days_around
  <date>     <dbl>       <int>
1 2020-01-21    NA          -3
2 2020-01-22    NA          -2
3 2020-01-23    NA          -1
4 2020-01-24     1           0
5 2020-01-25    NA           1
6 2020-01-26    NA           2
7 2020-01-27    NA           3
```

Comment: It's easier as I thought ;)

Comment: @TobKel yes, I guess you had thought about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
df %>% mutate(days_arround = 1:n() - (1:n())[!is.na(event)])

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  date       event days_arround
  <date>     <dbl>        <int>
1 2020-01-21    NA           -3
2 2020-01-22    NA           -2
3 2020-01-23    NA           -1
4 2020-01-24     1            0
5 2020-01-25    NA            1
6 2020-01-26    NA            2
7 2020-01-27    NA            3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
pos <- which(!is.na(df$event))
date_event <- as.Date(df$date[pos])

df <- df %>%
  mutate(days_around = df$date - date_event)
```